# Accessing the value of an object from a tuple without context information

Tags: python, types, type-conversion, tostring, hana

I have a list of IDs (IDList) that are a subset of a list of tupels, containing these IDs and related IDs in String-Format. There can be tupels with one related ID, e.g. (1694, '1743'), two related 
IDs seperated by comma e.g. (3252, '3253,3254') or no related ID ('none').

I would like to write all IDs from the tupels that are related to the IDs in IDList into one common list (final_list). Therefore the elements containing two IDs should be split by comma and those containing "none" should be dropped.

This is how my code looks right now:

```
IDList = [1694, 3252, 2779]
related = [(1694, '1743'), (3252, '3253,3254'), (3253, '3252,3254'), (3254, '3252,3253'), (1743, '1694'), (2779, 'none'), (3251, 'none'), (1677, 'none'), (1676, 'none'), (1678, '1679'), (1679, '1678')]
final_list = []
related_frame = pd.DataFrame(related)
print(related_frame)
for n in l:
    dset = related_frame.loc[related_frame[0] == n]
    print (dset)
    rel_set = dset[1]
    rel_set = str(rel_set)

    if "," in rel_set:
        rel_set = rel_set.split(',')

        print(rel_set)
    if "none" in rel_set:
        rel_set = []
    final_list.append(rel_set)

print(final_list)
```

In dataframe-format it still looks as expected:

```
print(related_frame)
```

out:

```
       0          1
0   1694       1743
1   3252  3253,3254
2   3253  3252,3254
3   3254  3252,3253
4   1743       1694
5   2779       none
6   3251       none
7   1677       none
8   1676       none
9   1678       1679
10  1679       1678
```

However, once I start working with the related values only, Python for some reason  adds information about the type to the values.

So the final_list looks like this:

```
print(final_list)

[['0    1743\nName: 1', ' dtype: object'], ['1    3253', '3254\nName: 1', ' dtype: object']]
```

I would like to have it this way:

```
print(final_list)

[1743, 3253, 3254]
```

Does anyone know how to access the values from the objects in the tupels without the \nName and dtype-information etc.? So I just would like to read the plain value. The data in the related-list is obtained from a varchar-column in SAP HANA-Database, so these are not very exceptional objects by any means.

I know I could remove them using

```
str.replace("\nName: 1', ' dtype: object", "")
```

But isn't there a more convenient way? The final_list would also look like this in that case (and I would prefer having it as stated above):

```
[['0    1743'], ['1    3253', '3254']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of regex and list comprehension.

```
import re
final_list = [['0    1743\nName: 1', ' dtype: object'], ['1    3253', '3254\nName: 1', ' dtype: object']]
print([int(i) for sublist in [re.findall(r'(?<!Name: )(\d+)(?=$|\n)', i) for sublist in final_list for i in sublist] for i in sublist])
```

This outputs:

```
[1743, 3253, 3254]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However  I was wondering if there really is no way to simply access the plain value of the object (as in the dataframe "related_frame" there are only the plain values displayed).
Your solution works, but it seems to be a lot of effort for a seemingly simple thing to do. If no one else comes up with a more convenient way to do it, e.g. a method, then I will accept as definite answer.